# Do references work across binary boundaries, or must you use a pointer?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

Given this interface defined in one binary:

```
struct ISomething
{
    virtual void __stdcall DoSomething() = 0;
};
```

Is this function signature, defined in another binary, safe?

```
bool __stdcall RunSomething(const ISomething &something);
```

or, *must* it be

```
bool __stdcall RunSomething(const ISomething *something);
```

*(Assume `__stdcall` is `#define`d to nothing on a non-Visual Studio compiler.)*

Comment: The question is a little unclear. I can have a binary declaration for `foo()` and a separate declaration for `foo()` in another binary and these two methods have no correlation. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @RageD For example, `RunSomething` could be exported from the main binary, and code within the shared object would call the function with a concrete implementation of `ISomething`.

Comment: If this didn't work, it would (practically) mean you couldn't have reference parameters in standard functions... kind of restraining. AFAIK, the C++ standard doesn't define anything for DLLs (or similar), so any answer would be implementation defined.

Comment: Oh - I was not aware that you were using a DLL (shared code), sorry about that.

Comment: @Mat Right: the standard doesn't define an ABI. Therefore, everything must be passed around as a pointer (for instance, passing `std::string` is asking for trouble, just pass a `const char *`). However, since `&` is really just syntactic sugar for `*` under the hood, I wonder if it's safe to use in this case.

Comment: You can pass `std::string&` around so long as all the code involved is working from the same implementation of the Standard C++ library, and so long as the same ABI is used. Is this not the case?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone if the same ABI is used and same standard library, then I think you are correct.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Yes, if everything is the same, passing a class reference is safe. However, I know in my particular case that most of the time compiler options will not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References should work fine between binaries. They're implemented at the assembly level as pointers. I think there are examples of this in the Standard C++ and Boost libraries (maybe `std::string::string(const std::string&)`).

You might run into trouble with name mangling, though, if the binaries weren't built with the same compiler and version, but that has nothing to do with references.

Comment: Actually `std::string::string` is `std::basic_string<char>::basic_string<char>`, a template function. Also if references are "implemented as pointers", does this mean references are implementation dependent and may not work with two binaries from two different compilers (even if the name mangling is the same)?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was suspecting, but I didn't want to end up shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Re: name mangling, the function should be wrapped with `extern "C"` when defined.

Comment: Yes, we could get into an argument over "what the C++ standard says" vs. "what every compiler in the past decade or two has implemented." In particular (taking Windows as an example), the OS and/or architecture imposes an ABI which determines the implementation of references and pointers. Evey single one I've seen treats them both the same (they're integer byte addresses) because the x86 (and ARM and others) architecture has no independent concept of a "reference".

Comment: Further, if different compilers did different things, their binaries couldn't interoperate at the *pointer* level, much less with references.

Comment: @moswald: `extern "C"` isn't always practical, as the functions might need to be in a class or namespace.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone (wrt your second to last comment) no, because they could do the same thing with pointers but different things with references. I'm just trying to caution the OP not to rely on anything not guaranteed. An implementation could, for example, make a reference a  small data structure or something. Not that any do, but they could and might in the future. A compiler reserves the right to break code relying on implementation-defined behaviour :)

Comment: Seth: That's exactly what I was referring to. The C++ standard allows implementations to do insane things, such as arbitrarily deciding to implement references as something (what exactly?) other than pointers at the assembly level. So it becomes a case of which audience are you trying to satisfy: the Standards-followers or the actual platforms your code will run on? BTW, my other point was that an implementation could, to use your example, make a pointer a small structure as well. Which is pretty much what a "huge pointer" *is.* Yet even then a reference is sugar for a pointer.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone True. In my particular case, I'm aiming for maximum compatibility with regards to compiler versions and options (ie, debug vs. release builds). `extern "C"` isn't a huge burden. :)

Comment: I'd be really surprised if the *ABI* made pointers the same as references for a Debug build but not a Release build. If the implementations change at all, why wouldn't they change for both? P.S. There is one place where using a reference would be a problem: if you were expecting your library to be called from *C*.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: abide by the standard and you automatically keep all implementers happy. That's why we have one in the first place. It's not a document of suggestions.

Comment: Umm, no. Complying with standards only gets you standards compliance. It doesn't guarantee implementation support. [Not even GCC really supports the C++ standard.](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) You *cannot* write production code without dealing with the limits of your architecture, OS, libraries, and toolchain. That's why we have, for example, cmake and autohell. (P.S. so long as any of the standard is "implementation defined", it *is* a document of suggestions.)